# I need a good font manager for mac and/or windows

Tags: windows, mac, fonts

I'm looking for a full featured font manager (support all formats - ttf, otf, ps, etc.). I use both Mac and Windows. The font manager does not need to be free but it does need to be under $100. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac OS X you can look at [FontExplorer X Pro](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/) (not free). On that site you'll also find Linotype Font Explorer X, which is free and should be enough (last link on [this](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/download/) page).

You can also find a few more apps [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/05/25-font-management-tools-reviewed/), both for Windows, and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

[Suitcase Fusion 2](http://www.extensis.com/) and [FontAgent Pro](http://insidersoftware.com/) are ones I've used, and they are both available for Windows and OS X. Of the two, I prefer FontAgent Pro, although these days I just manage the fonts manually.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Typograf](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/) which is a windows based font manager. $35.

Answer (score 0):

Second vote for FontAgent Pro. I work for a print media corporation, and we use it all over the place for literally thousands of fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I really am partial to [Fontcase](http://bohemiancoding.com/fontcase/). Allows you to preview and compare fonts, along with a powerful tagging system. And it's only a bit over $50.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

[AMP Font Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php) handles/browses all uninstalled and installed fonts.

[FontPicker](http://www.charten.com/Products/FontPicker.htm) is a handy comparative tool to compare installed fonts.

If you are mainly interested in reviewing your installed fonts the free [Fast Font Preview](http://www.lanmisoft.com/fastfontpreview.htm) provides a quick multi-line view, but doesn't review all types of uninstalled fonts.

For fonts containing Unicode characters see [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html). See also this neat [Unicode Viewer](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=26&Itemid).

See also [Advanced Font Viewer](http://www.styopkin.com/).